# NAT configuration for HTTP server

Tags: firewall, http, nat

There is a router (192.168.1.1) having static public IP(hypothetically- 8.8.8.8). This router is programmed to forward all incoming port 80 (TCP/UDP) connections to a particular IP (192.168.1.105). Forwarding is done through NAT - Virtual host configuration (print screen attached). Firewall and SPI are disabled on the router.

When I save the router configuration I get a success message and a prompt indicating that CPE login (router login) is shifted to port 8080 (meaning to log to the router I will have to enter router IP 192.168.1.1:8080, print screen attached)

IP (192.168.1.105) is WAN port of a firewall. There is a rule created on firewall which forwards all incoming connections to a particular IP located on DMZ port of the firewall (10.0.0.5).

Here is the problem:

Whenever a request is sent to public IP (8.8.8.8), router login page appears (192.168.1.1). While it should technically transfer the request to the HTTP server

I have checked by creating a DMZ on the router and creating a virtual host + DMZ on the router. However in both cases router's configuration page login screen appears.

Anyone has any idea How I can configure the router and the firewall to enable a HTTP server!

[image]

Comment: Can you find under the remote management settings (maybe Access Management?) where it set the port number for remote management, and confirm that it is 8080?  Sounds like that didn't get changed correctly.

Comment: Sadly, there are no other options for login. There is no way to disable HTTP (80) and enable only HTTPS (443). There's no way to even change the default login ID. x.x

Comment: I've found  that the problem -- is the FIREWALL.
Here is what i did - I connected the server directly to the ISP WiFi router and kept the same port forward configuration and changed servers ethernet interface IP to the IP where router is configured to forward the traffic. AND IT WORKED !!!
I changed it back to ISP Router to Firewall to Server and the same login page.
It's clear that the problem is the Firewall. I need to now figure out which rule is causing the router to fail and shows its own login page and the HTTP server not the receive any request.